# Target class LogoutController does not exist yet it does

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel 9

When I click on a link with the route /logout I get the following error:
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\LogoutController] does not exist. Yet it does exist and the file is there. The file path to LogoutController.php is app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LogoutController.php

If I do a refresh I get a different error:
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. But the method is POST not GET.
Here is my web.php line for the route and the class is imported using use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController; :

```
Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'logout_user'])->name('logout');
```

Here is my LogoutController in the Auth directory

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LogoutController extends Controller
{
    public function logout_user()
    {
        auth()->logout();
    }
}
```

Here is the link for the route:

```
        <li>
          <form action="{{route('logout')}}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          <button>Logout</button>
          </form>
        </li>
```

All the other routes that are the same work why is this one not working? Help to fix is appreciated.

Comment: What is the file path to your controller?

Comment: use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController;

Comment: That is the namespace, not the path, where is the file located? and what is the filename

Comment: I'm disregarding the first error since Simon is helping you figure it out. I'll instead ask you if you have `method="POST"` in your logout button?

Comment: I edited my question and provided more detail

Comment: You say your controller is in the Auth folder, The laravel namespace is based on the path of the file. as explained in my answer. So you are missing the `\Auth` in your namespace

Comment: I disagree on the question being closed on "typo", A wrong namespace is not a typo and is a very common mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your namespace is not correct:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

needs to be

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

Make sure it is located in the correct folder and the use statements are correct.

Also add the use statement for the extended controller

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

Comment: Cannot do that because then Controller in 'extends Controller' becomes undefined

Comment: Add a use statement for the controller: `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller` edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forget to import the class in your route.
e.g `use App\Http\Controllers\LogoutController;`

Comment: since the namespace is not correct, this will not work